# Rspec/capybara have_text fail but include pass

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

Can't figure out this very strange behavior.
This will pass

`expect(html_string).to include reset_url`

These will fail

`expect(html_string).to have_text reset_url`

`expect(html_string).to have_link reset_url`

And the error message is `expected to find text but there were no matches`. So it's not a forgetting to include spec_helper mistake.

**And I have double checked the html_string does have the entire reset_url. They are NOT invisible content**

**Plus I have other specs (in the same spec file) that use `have_text` and `have_link` passing.**

edit: Not sure why the vote down without comment. But if you are voting down, please provide a comment or and thought you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What stands out to me here is that the `include` matcher is built into RSpec, while `have_text` and `have_link` are included via the Capybara::RSpecMatchers module.

If your other specs are passing as expected, your `rails_helper` should be requiring the `capybara/dsl` just fine.

Is it possible that you're missing `require 'rails_helper'` in this particular spec, but including it in the others?

Comment: The ones that pass and the ones that doesn't are in the same file. That's what bothers me.